# x86 Can push/pop be less than 4 bytes?

Tags: memory, assembly, x86, stack

Hi I am reading a guide on x86 by the University of Virginia and it states that pushing and popping the stack either removes or adds a 4-byte data element to the stack.

Why is this set to 4 bytes? Can this be changed, could you save memory on the stack by pushing on smaller data elements?

The guide can be found here if anyone wishes to view it:
http://www.cs.virginia.edu/~evans/cs216/guides/x86.html

Comment: That statement only sort of applies in 32bit mode, and you can also push/pop 2-byte elements.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Short answer: Yes, 16 or 32 bits. And, for [x86-64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86-64), 64 bits.

The primary reasons for a stack are to return from nested function calls and to save/restore register values. It is also typically used to pass parameters and return function results. Except for the smallest parameters, these items usually have the same size by the design of the processor, namely, the size of the instruction pointer register. For 8088/8086, it is 16-bits. For 80386 and successors, it is 32-bits. Therefore, there is little value in having stack instructions that operate on other sizes.

There is also the consideration of the size of the data on the memory bus. It takes the same amount of time to retrieve or store a word as it does a byte. (Except for 8088 which has 16-bit registers but an 8-bit data bus.) Alignment also comes into play. The stack should be aligned on word boundaries so each value can be retrieved as one memory operation. The trade-off is usually taken to save time over saving memory. To pass one byte as a parameter, one word is usually used. (Or, depending on the optimization available to the compiler, one word-sized register would be used, avoiding the stack altogether.)

Comment: In x86-64 you can't push 32-bit registers or values stored in memory, only 16- or 64-bit registers and values stored in memory. `push ax`, `push rax`, `push word [rax]` and `push qword [rax]` are all valid x86-64 instructions, but `push eax` and `push dword [rax]` are not valid in x86-64.

Comment: Historical note, the (very rarely used) 80188 (16-bit word, 8-bit data bus) and (somewhat popular for a time) 386SX (32-bit word, 16-bit data bus) were in the same boat as the 8088 regarding data bus size mismatch.

Comment: For "The stack should be aligned on word boundaries so each value can be retrieved as one memory operation.", does this apply to local variables inside a function?

Comment: @Thomson. Yes, compilers do arrange local variables on the stack and in registers so that access time is optimized. There is usually no requirement for local variables to laid out on the stack in any order or without padding.