# Why does gcc pass char type in 8 byte format to function assembly

Tags: c, assembly, gcc, x86-64, calling-convention

To learn assembly I am viewing the assembly generated by GCC using the -S command for some simple c programs.  I have an add function which accepts some ints and some char and adds them together.  I am just wondering why the char parameters are pushed onto the stack as 8 bytes (pushq)?  Why not just push a single byte?

```
    .file   "test.c"
    .text
    .globl  add
    .type   add, @function
add:
.LFB0:
    .cfi_startproc
    pushq   %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    .cfi_offset 6, -16
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_register 6
    movl    %edi, -4(%rbp)
    movl    %esi, -8(%rbp)
    movl    %edx, -12(%rbp)
    movl    %ecx, -16(%rbp)
    movl    %r8d, -20(%rbp)
    movl    %r9d, -24(%rbp)
    movl    16(%rbp), %ecx
    movl    24(%rbp), %edx
    movl    32(%rbp), %eax
    movb    %cl, -28(%rbp)
    movb    %dl, -32(%rbp)
    movb    %al, -36(%rbp)
    movl    -4(%rbp), %edx
    movl    -8(%rbp), %eax
    addl    %eax, %edx
    movl    -12(%rbp), %eax
    addl    %eax, %edx
    movl    -16(%rbp), %eax
    addl    %eax, %edx
    movl    -20(%rbp), %eax
    addl    %eax, %edx
    movl    -24(%rbp), %eax
    addl    %eax, %edx
    movsbl  -28(%rbp), %eax
    addl    %eax, %edx
    movsbl  -32(%rbp), %eax
    addl    %eax, %edx
    movsbl  -36(%rbp), %eax
    addl    %edx, %eax
    popq    %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa 7, 8
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
.LFE0:
    .size   add, .-add
    .globl  main
    .type   main, @function
main:
.LFB1:
    .cfi_startproc
    pushq   %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    .cfi_offset 6, -16
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_register 6
    pushq   $9
    pushq   $8
    pushq   $7
    movl    $6, %r9d
    movl    $5, %r8d
    movl    $4, %ecx
    movl    $3, %edx
    movl    $2, %esi
    movl    $1, %edi
    call    add
    addq    $24, %rsp
    leave
    .cfi_def_cfa 7, 8
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
.LFE1:
    .size   main, .-main
    .ident  "GCC: (Ubuntu 4.9.2-10ubuntu13) 4.9.2"
    .section    .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
```

```
#include <stdio.h>

int add(int a, int b, int c, int d, int e, int f, char g, char h, char i)
{
    return a + b + c + d + e + f + g + h + i;
}

int main()
{
    return add(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9);
}
```

Comment: The stack must be aligned to the word size of the system. So it wouldn't make sense to be able to push a single byte unless that was the word size.

Comment: I do not seen any `char`s.

Comment: @alk - in the generated asm, neither does the op, hence the question. The `char`s are parameters of the `add` function in the code snippet. ;)

Comment: @enhzflep: "*The `char`s are parameters of the add function in the code snippet.*" No, they aren't.  `1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9` are interger literals, which go as `int` by definition. Yes, this does not explain why the compiler uses twice their size on the stack.

Comment: @alk - okay, so how would you describe parameters `g`, `h` and `i` then? Also, by my reckoning, `rbp` is 8 times the width of `al`.

Comment: Ups, I indeed missed the last three, my bad. Sry! Still `7, 8, 9` are in integer literals, `int`s. And as I said in my previous comment: *"this does not explain why the compiler uses twice [quatuble] their size on the stack.*" That's why I do not "answer", but "only" comment here. @enhzflep There surely are others with more expertice on what happens on asm level.

Comment: @chasep255 - the code you show is x64 code. Therefore, the word size is 64 bits or 8 bytes. This is the smallest container of data that should be put onto the stack. Whether or not the container is full is irrelevant.

Comment: @alk: It doesn't matter if they're `int` literals or not --- they're all implicitly converted to `char`, because that's what the parameters are. Also, note that @enhzflep was talking about *parameters*, and you were talking about *arguments* (and before type conversion, at that).

Comment: Better compile with `gcc -O1 -S -fverbose-asm`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When pushing values onto the stack, the push must always be based on the word size of the system.  If you're an old timer like me, that's 16 bits (though I do have some 12 bit word size systems!), but it really is system dependent.

Since you're talking about X86_64, you will be talking about 64 bit words.  My understanding is that the word size is typically connected to the minimum number of bytes required to address any value on the RAM of the system.  Since you have a 64 bit memory space, a 64 bit (or 8 bytes, a "quad word" based on the original 16 bit word size) is required.

Answer (score 11):

**GCC is following the x86-64 System V ABI**, which was designed to use stack slots the same width as full registers, like earlier 16 and 32-bit x86 calling conventions, and like typical ABIs for other machines.

This has a few advantages, like making it possible to use `push` fairly simply for stack args, even with a mix of constants and variables.  And being more robust in some cases when code is sloppy about arg types for variadic (like `printf`) or unprototyped functions (e.g. implicit function declarations, or K&R-style declarations like `int add();` without an arg list, either of which were maybe still a consideration in 2000 when the x86-64 SysV ABI was designed publicly on a mailing list whose archives give some insight into stuff [like the choice of those six arg-passing registers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4429398/why-does-windows64-use-a-different-calling-convention-from-all-other-oses-on-x86/35619528#35619528).) Sloppy C and C++ was more common than hopefully now.

x86-64 System V is an [LP64 ABI](https://unix.org/version2/whatsnew/lp64_wp.html) (Long and Pointers are 64-bit), so code that passes a `long` to a function expecting an `int` (variadic like `printf("%d %d", sizeof(foo), my_long)`, or no prototype) would break later args in a hypothetical calling-convention where 64-bit `long` took more space than 32-bit `int`.

(Such a design would be *possible*, with stack args laid out following the struct rules above RSP, so each is aligned by its `alignof()`.  Valid ISO C programs without UB would still work. POSIX's numbered printf stuff like `printf(%2$Lf %1$d\n", 1, (long double)2.2)` at first looks like it needs more functionality, but each arg must be mentioned by the format string so a possible implementation is to just retrieve or index them all in sequence.  Even x86-64 System V doesn't make an array of fixed-width args that you can easily index.)

**An implicit declaration of your `add`** (e.g. if `main` was in a separate file without a prototype) would also break in a narrow-arg-packing convention even if you passed the last 3 args as `(char)7`.
C default argument promotion for variadic and unprototyped functions will expand `char` and other narrow integer types to `int`, which actually still works on 2's complement machines like x86 even if the caller is expecting `char`<sup>1</sup>, if the calling convention pads narrow args to at least `int` width. (ISO C doesn't define the behaviour, but unless `-flto` sees the mismatch, the calling convention effectively does define the behaviour.)

On 32-bit machines, `int` was full register width, so there's the precedent for using full register width.  And `long` was generally also that width, so some code was probably sloppy about mixing `long` and `int`, but would have broken on existing 32-bit systems if sloppy in the same way about `long long`.  Making the arg-passing slots as wide as `long` in x86-64 System V lets some functions still happen to work that wouldn't have with `int`-sized slots.

This normally isn't a disaster in terms of wasting stack space or taking too many instructions (multiple `push imm8` instead of one one `push imm32`):  Most functions get most of their args in registers (and can pack them if they want/need to spill them, e.g. if they have to call another function before using them).  The C++ ABI does force "non-trivial" (constructor/destructor) class types to be passed in memory, though. (e.g. *[Why can a T* be passed in register, but a unique_ptr<T> cannot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58339165/why-can-a-t-be-passed-in-register-but-a-unique-ptrt-cannot)*)  The code in your example `add` callee is terrible because you didn't enable optimization, but the code in your `main` looks normal.

---

##### x86-64 System V details and stated motivation

See https://gitlab.com/x86-psABIs/x86-64-ABI for a copy of the current version of the spec.  See also the [x86](/questions/tagged/x86) [tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info) for links to ABIs (and much more good stuff.)  From page 23 of the ABI PDF:

> **Classification** The size of each argument gets rounded up to eightbytes*.
> (*footnote: Therefore the stack will always be eightbyte aligned).

That's not the most convincing justification.  I think the hypothetical situation where narrow args would temporarily misalign RSP is that you'd still `push` narrow args one at a time, perhaps with `pushw $1` for 2-byte args (or `pushw $0x0201` for two 1-byte args?), or even emulating dword pushes<sup>2</sup> with `sub $4, %rsp` / `mov %eax, (%rsp)` or dec/mov for bytes.  That would obviously be silly, you'd just move RSP once and use `mov` to store args.  Or like GCC `-maccumulate-outgoing-args` to only move RSP once for the whole function, reusing arg-passing space<sup>3</sup>.

And you still have to end up with `RSP % 16 == 0` before the `call` - (pg 16: **Stack Frame**):

> The end of the input argument area shall be aligned on a 16 (32, if
> `__m256` is passed on stack) byte boundary.  In other words, the value
> (`%rsp + 8`) is always a multiple of 16 (32) when control is
> transferred to the function entry point.

If they'd designed it so different integer types had different widths on the stack, but 8-byte types were still always 8-byte aligned, there would be slightly more complicated rules about where the padding goes, (and thus where the called function finds its args) depending on the types of current and previous args.

And `va_arg` for variadic functions like printf would be even more complex, needing to round up a pointer to the next alignment boundary for the type in case the previous arg ended at an insufficiently-aligned location.

---

##### Footnote 1 - `char`/`short`/`int` compatibility

The low byte of an `int8_t` or `uint8_t` sign or zero-extended to `int` is still the same `int8_t` or `uint8_t` object-representation, for 2's complement or unsigned.

So the caller extending it because of default arg promotions doesn't break anything as long as it's still passed in one fixed-width slot.  (ISO C doesn't define the behaviour but I'm sure in practice it wasn't rare for old codebases to depend on this.)  This isn't true for `float`/`double`, but lots of functions only use `double` if they use FP at all.

A longer explanation with more background follows; feel free to skip it.

With a function defined like `int add(many args, char g, char h, char i)` (or the K&R equivalent which doesn't act as a prototype), the callee knows it's only looking for narrow args.  But callers that don't have a prototype (perhaps only a declaration like `int add();`, or worse an implicit declaration) will follow C's default argument promotions so `(char)1` implicitly becomes `(int)(char)1`.   (C11 [N1570 6.5.2.2 / 6](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf#page=99)).

Such a caller has to assume the callee was written to take an `int` arg at that position, so it definitely needs to pass a full `int`.

ISO C doesn't define the behaviour when the callee expects `char` but the caller (after default argument promotions) passes `int`. (That's why it's `putchar(int)` for example; the stdio package predates prototypes and even the preprocessor.)  However, most calling conventions *do* define the behaviour for narrow integer types, at least when `-flto` doesn't let the compiler see you breaking the rules and decide this code path must be unreachable or something.

A `float` arg won't work for functions with unprototyped callers: they'll promote it to `double`.  The low 32 bits of a `double` interpreted as an IEEE binary32 `float` bit-pattern don't represent the same number.  (Often 0.0 for round numbers like 3.0).  So functions with unprototyped callers can't take a `float`, even with a slot width of 8 bytes so later args are in the right position.  (Same for variadic args, which is [why `printf` has no conversion for `float`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37082784/how-to-print-a-single-precision-float-with-printf), because any caller will promote it to `double`.)

But 2's complement and unsigned integer types sign/zero extend just by tacking on copies of the sign bit, or zeros respectively.  This doesn't change the bits of the narrower integer, so those low bits are still a valid `signed char` or `unsigned short`.  A caller that was expecting `int8_t` will still read the right value whether the caller wrote only a byte or a whole dword with extra copies of the sign bit above it.

**Note that args in x86-64 System V *can* contain garbage outside the actual C type width**, in a register or the stack slot.  Same for return values.  (This is why compilers sometimes do `movsxd` or `mov edx, edi` for int or unsigned args before using them to index an array.  Actually I'm being over-optimistic: usually they stupidly do `mov edi,edi` which defeats mov-elimination.  So `size_t` args can be better in functions that don't inline.)
Clang relies on an undocumented extension which GCC also implements for the caller side but doesn't rely on, [where narrow args are extended to 32-bit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36706721/is-a-sign-or-zero-extension-required-when-adding-a-32bit-offset-to-a-pointer-for/36760539#36760539), as if by default argument promotion, in both registers and stack memory, for functions with prototypes.  So even callers with prototypes should extend args to 32-bit when calling into clang-compiled code.  This is often something you want to do anyway, e.g. `movzx` for byte loads from memory.

The key point here is that a call to `int add(a,b) : char a,b; {return a+b;}` ([K&R style declaration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3092006/function-declaration-kr-vs-ansi)) with no prototype anywhere will result in the caller writing 4-byte args (in 8-byte slots in x86-64 System V) and the caller reading 1-byte args from the correct places (the least-significant bytes of what the caller wrote), so it all Just Works.  For registers or for later args on the stack.

But if `add` looked for its two `char` args in adjacent bytes, that would only work for callers that saw a prototype and placed their args accordingly, different from `int` args.

On the other hand, `long foo(a, b) long a,b; {return a+b}` with a caller that does `foo(1, (int)x)` (without seeing a prototype) is *not* guaranteed to work without a prototype.  (Even in practice on x86-64, even with the unofficial extension  Clang relies on: that's only to 32-bit).  If the caller uses `mov` to store args to memory (like `gcc -maccumulate-outgoing-args`), it's probably only going to write a dword for each, leaving the garbage in the high bytes that the caller *is* going to read.  (For register args, often those will be zero-extended to 64-bit from writing the 32-bit register (because [that's how the x86-64 ISA works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11177137/why-do-x86-64-instructions-on-32-bit-registers-zero-the-upper-part-of-the-full-6)) so that already doesn't work for signed negative values, and you can [construct cases](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYTStJg1AB9U8lJL6yAngGVG6AMKpaAVxYMJATlIOAMngMmABy7gBGmMQS0gAOqAqEtgzObh7epHEJNgIBQaEsEVFSFphW2QxCBEzEBCnunlw%2BlpjWSZXVBLkh4ZHRFlU1dWmN/R1d%2BYXRAJQWqK7EyOwcAPTLAKQATADMgchuWADUa1uOCgT4qAB0CMfYaxoAgvcPq4EEB0zo6BBTxwBCzwOywAVAcAJIMA6ObYHAgIPAKA4Ig60PAAa0wUM2AI2fw%2BDHQBzYhkRbw%2BXwgADdUHh0L8tgDHgcDqCIQdMNVUZEDmdDOhqugFKQke96ExKZhEXDMdVgIjXAwFDEWngaJh0JdASyoQYjDymABPKXw0mIrAxYgtJgEdVIyGbDZiWgOg4S4gJASI1BUKGXZkAWUNEQO2lcZwOYQNOsMwGOADEWetHs9NjsfRpnmTPt8s8KyWE84IDuY7e90IX3pgKwcqMLkAhqgdgHWG8QDggW428FMjgB2RkPZnMy0EeaQphHXERyd45Azg6E7Hs%2Bc%2BpfAecIed4f4p3sAERT2wcqpTj2ptNLVAVyAgb3pA%2Be58J/FQEFoAnXql%2B/a1zNWdrQFhAnXAA2SQAFowkIV0xFcTFAgOAAlPcwV/IFlgOAB3QhNwYVA7TOYhXFaT0I0wfhLQ%2BWEmDoURaFoYU8LhYDYSIhhRBtUkCE1Jkh1WVRsUEhk/ww7D6NY69rUxaUYLcaT8K2DZIOghJ2OkhBMTo%2BhMQEWgoyCdVEUU5TuLQ6kDBsegUQ/HlAjRI4tj3GdsQE4T0IOMNJVhDSDjAkzZLgnl8OghspXwzzfIgqD3lQZViD5cCEgAL0wNC3ivdiIC/Hdk33Z4OBmWhOAAVl4TwOC0UhUE4RwgvmRZJy2HhSAITQCpmDTPl6H5SDREAti2S5JF7LwQIADi2Yre17DYNGKsafCKjhJF4FgJA0DRSHKyrqo4XgFBATbWoqgrSDgWAYEQFBUBYGI6EichKEAu76CiZBgC4RS%2BDoG13UoMI2tIKDmGIA1OGa4HqgNAB5MJtBaY7msAthBGhhg9MBrAwlcYBHCdA7uF4LAWBjcQTtIfBLVaCUCcqzBVBaVwbXB3g3lKQHUTCeLQecLBAYIYg8DWwmZioAw5QANTwTBMOh5Vyua/hBBEMR2GKJX5CUNRAd0DZ9BjEBTGMcxOYOyAZli8oCfAgB1J0DkS85jj3YAGFcLhewdm36YFidwOhjYHeVflBDwOdbcIsOCHAi1UCIAgDWVRFbbw8CFU89BeFQN1BawM2euaEjPAgBwhgaXwCXGHoigyeJEgEMu9EyeuGCrgpei4EoyjaAZahceo9EL8p2hqNvJk73lBn74ZRlHwJunbooZgUOYFjVwqSrKwHdoOVQxpA8CwKbZA50%2By5A4gXBCBIRquCmXhjq0KYOo5LAoh6vqBsuT6xsaUbe0kBNECIENAgX0JwFapA1rFU2ttLOnB9qHRam1GY50rpzAIDEJmj0IDPXusQYIrAlh7wPkfYAJ8Dhnw2LwdU19c56A1ircQ6tZCKBUOocmutSCYXijEFmG8OClS2tvTg0MmZYJij6Ehh9JDH1PoNC%2Bzhbr4Mahse%2ByCTrP1IJ1N%2BlABGQOgbAkRe0LBIMfu1Xq/VBpcH3l4CaGgFqSBASNcBHAthb3JrtB%2BKCzqXTQRAJAeDXo4KCb0E%2BuoPq9g0J3GgtBfoHQgADcmkNQYsyBoEKGsN4bWDScjRgBA0YY3JljHGeN6IE2asTUmSxKqUwRngGmgN6aM2ZoTcggh2bk05tzA0vMakP0FsLHgotxYKCljLOWjA0mMLomraQGs2Ha04f1fWRhDZmH0HgMI%2BcLYxCtpwf2gdHboGdq7d2ntbb2y9qndOShM5VRzrSSU8Bl6lHqXYEuBJG6d38PPCYHda5ZCSN8wFLcx4AqHj3DoILIUCBHp0P51dB69xhb3cFS9Zj1XXq4oRcCqqcF3vvGRxYImUN7JcDQ38DiX3wEQNsqY77eM0S/Lq78Zif0GgNLl3KeWuIMSAGBwjPEINMUdHx/ikAYIkSEm6L1IiELYJwaRR89gxjJRS7%2BNDaUkFpAw2QTC5kyEEIsjhlVdBbG4bw/hOKPE7VEeIpmBxvSEtIbI1VeoPYaq4NSpRcr6XbC2Oo8xWidHdX0atAVRjhUmIOmK5lliv48qTVy1x7ihV2pMcGgR1D03wMzSgmYboPSeEkEAA%3D%3D) where the compiler can leave garbage in the high 32 bits of RDI when calling a function that wants an `int`.)  Other than K&R definitions, if headers only have `long foo();` or nothing, then from other compilation units callers are in the same boat even if some other `.c` used `long foo(long a, long b){...}`.

Default argument promotion up to `int` saves the day for passing `char` or `int` to functions that wanted `int` or `char` even without prototypes, but not for functions that want args wider than `int`.  (This includes `long` for x86-64 System V, but not for Windows x64 which chose an LLP64 ABI: only `long long` and pointers are 64-bit.  But includes `size_t` for both.)

#### Footnote 2 - operand sizes for `push`

8-bit pushes are not encodable at all, in any mode.  In 64-bit mode, only 16-bit (with a `0x66` prefix), or 64-bit (no prefix, or `REX.W=1`) are available.

The "description" and pseudocode part of Intel's [manual entry](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/push) are confusing on this, saying that REX can override the operand-size and having a clause for 32-bit operand-size with 64-bit address-size.  But `push dword` is not encodeable in 64-bit mode even with REX.W=0: the table at the top is correct, the "RSP := RSP – 4" in the pseudocode is unreachable.  See
*[How many bytes does the push instruction push onto the stack when I don't specify the operand size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45127993/how-many-bytes-does-the-push-instruction-pushes-onto-the-stack-when-i-dont-spec)*.

#### Footnote 3:  push vs. mov for storing args:

GCC `-maccumulate-outgoing-args` ([using `mov`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4534791/why-does-gcc-use-movl-instead-of-push-to-pass-function-args)) was generally faster anyway when AMD64 was new, before Pentium M and later AMD had a stack engine to avoid uops that update RSP.  But larger code-size in bytes, since `push reg` is a 1-byte instruction.  And code-size both for L1i hit rate and fetch/decode bandwidth was a factor on early CPUs before uop caches.

x86-64 System V's actual design does make `push reg` and `push imm8/imm32` fairly efficiently usable for functions with so many args that they need some on the stack (or C++ functions with non-POD args that must go in memory).  Since you need the last push to leave `RSP % 16 == 0`, you might need a dummy push or something to reach the right starting point for however many args you're going to push.

(Unlike Windows x64 with shadow space below the stack args, where you normally don't use `push`.  And apparently stack-unwind info doesn't want you to change RSP except in function prologue or epilogue, unless you're using RBP as a frame pointer to allow alloca.)

---

PS: This got way longer than I intended, and I had a hard time boiling it down.  It could probably use a proof-read; let me know if there's any dangling sentence fragments or duplicated points.  (There's a bunch of first-draft stuff in an HTML comment in case I come back to it.)

Other Q&As on the subject:

- [Why function parameter occupy at least 4 bytes stack on x86?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30679702/why-function-parameter-occupy-at-least-4-bytes-stack-on-x86) (32-bit mode)
- [Why argument's size of function is increased to word size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57794171/why-arguments-size-of-function-is-increased-to-word-size) (where they mean register width, not an x86 `word`).
- [Why there are holes on the stack when passing parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52547730/why-there-are-holes-on-the-stack-when-passing-parameters)
- [Why are parameters arranged this way on the stack when a function is called?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60959847/why-are-parameters-arranged-this-way-on-the-stack-when-a-function-is-called)

Comment: It's probably not just the ABI. I don't think you can actually push (using a PUSH opcode) anything  but full register size (e.g. EAX for 32 bit or  RAX for 64 bit) in x86-32 or x86-64 mode (but I'm prepared to be proven wrong). You could of course emulate pushes of smaller sizes by simply placing the values on the stack and updating the stack pointer, but that is not really pushing, IMO.

Comment: Yeah, you're right.  `PUSH r/m32` and `PUSH r32` are not encodable in 64bit mode.  Only 64 and 16bit (operand-size prefix) pushes are available.  8b pushes aren't available at all.

Comment: Why 16 bit and not 32 bit.  Also why not 1 byte.

Comment: 16bit is encoded with an operand-size prefix before the opcode.  8-bit for most instructions is encoded with a different opcode (because for 8086 -> 80286, they made new opcodes instead of changing the default size for existing ones, I think).  And there is no 8-bit `push` opcode.

Comment: Why no 32?  IDK, I think they could have had the `W` bit of the `REX` prefix allow a 32bit operand size for `push`/`pop`.  Actually, the text description says this is supported.  It just doesn't show up in the table of opcodes.