# Why there are holes on the stack when passing parameters?

Tags: assembly, x86-64, disassembly, calling-convention

I am not quite familiar with assembly code. Excuse me if this question is naive.

I have a simple C program:

```
int f1(int a1, int a2, int a3, int a4, int a5, int a6, int a7, int a8, int a9)
{
  int c = 3;
  int d = 4;
  return a1 + a2 + a3 + a4 + a5 + a6 + a7 + a8 + a9 + c + d;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  f1(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9);
}
```

I compiled it into an **elf64-x86-64** and get below disassembly code:

f1():

```
0000000000000000 <f1>:
   0:   55                      push   %rbp
   1:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
   4:   89 7d ec                mov    %edi,-0x14(%rbp)      ; 1
   7:   89 75 e8                mov    %esi,-0x18(%rbp)       ; 2
   a:   89 55 e4                mov    %edx,-0x1c(%rbp)      ; 3
   d:   89 4d e0                mov    %ecx,-0x20(%rbp)      ; 4
  10:   44 89 45 dc             mov    %r8d,-0x24(%rbp)  ; 5
  14:   44 89 4d d8             mov    %r9d,-0x28(%rbp)  ; 6
  18:   c7 45 f8 03 00 00 00    movl   $0x3,-0x8(%rbp) ; c = 3
  1f:   c7 45 fc 04 00 00 00    movl   $0x4,-0x4(%rbp) ; d = 4
  26:   8b 45 e8                mov    -0x18(%rbp),%eax     ;2
  29:   8b 55 ec                mov    -0x14(%rbp),%edx    ; 1
  2c:   01 c2                   add    %eax,%edx                
  2e:   8b 45 e4                mov    -0x1c(%rbp),%eax     ;3
  31:   01 c2                   add    %eax,%edx
  33:   8b 45 e0                mov    -0x20(%rbp),%eax     ;4
  36:   01 c2                   add    %eax,%edx
  38:   8b 45 dc                mov    -0x24(%rbp),%eax     ;5
  3b:   01 c2                   add    %eax,%edx
  3d:   8b 45 d8                mov    -0x28(%rbp),%eax    ; 6
  40:   01 c2                   add    %eax,%edx
  42:   8b 45 10                mov    0x10(%rbp),%eax     ;7
  45:   01 c2                   add    %eax,%edx
  47:   8b 45 18                mov    0x18(%rbp),%eax    ; 8
  4a:   01 c2                   add    %eax,%edx
  4c:   8b 45 20                mov    0x20(%rbp),%eax    ; 9
  4f:   01 c2                   add    %eax,%edx
  51:   8b 45 f8                mov    -0x8(%rbp),%eax    ; c =3
  54:   01 c2                   add    %eax,%edx
  56:   8b 45 fc                mov    -0x4(%rbp),%eax    ; d =4
  59:   01 d0                   add    %edx,%eax
  5b:   5d                      pop    %rbp
  5c:   c3                      retq
```

main():

```
000000000000005d <main>:
  5d:   55                      push   %rbp
  5e:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
  61:   48 83 ec 30             sub    $0x30,%rsp
  65:   89 7d fc                mov    %edi,-0x4(%rbp)
  68:   48 89 75 f0             mov    %rsi,-0x10(%rbp)
  6c:   c7 44 24 10 09 00 00    movl   $0x9,0x10(%rsp)
  73:   00 
  74:   c7 44 24 08 08 00 00    movl   $0x8,0x8(%rsp)
  7b:   00 
  7c:   c7 04 24 07 00 00 00    movl   $0x7,(%rsp)
  83:   41 b9 06 00 00 00       mov    $0x6,%r9d
  89:   41 b8 05 00 00 00       mov    $0x5,%r8d
  8f:   b9 04 00 00 00          mov    $0x4,%ecx
  94:   ba 03 00 00 00          mov    $0x3,%edx
  99:   be 02 00 00 00          mov    $0x2,%esi
  9e:   bf 01 00 00 00          mov    $0x1,%edi
  a3:   b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
  a8:   e8 00 00 00 00          callq  ad <main+0x50>
  ad:   c9                      leaveq 
  ae:   c3                      retq
```

It seems there are some **holes** on the stack when passing parameters from `main()` to `f1()`:

[image]

My questions are:

- Why need these holes?
- And why do we need below 2 lines of assembly? If they are meant for context restoring, I don't see any instructions to do that. And the `%rsi` register is NOT even used elsewhere. Why still save `%rsi` on stack?

`65: 89 7d fc                mov    %edi,-0x4(%rbp)
    68: 48 89 75 f0             mov    %rsi,-0x10(%rbp)`

- And just came up with one more question, since the args `1 ~ 6` have already been passed via the **registers**, why move them **back to memory** at the beginning of `f1()`?

Comment: Arg passing uses 8-byte "slots" on the stack.  Re: spilling RSI: you're compiling without optimization, so for consistent debugging every variable including function args needs a memory address.

Comment: Upvote for all the effort that went into illustrating this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arg passing in the x86-64 System V ABI uses 8-byte "slots" on the stack, for args that don't fit in registers.  Anything that isn't a multiple of 8 bytes will have holes (padding) before the next stack arg.

This is pretty standard for calling conventions across OSes / architectures.  Passing a `short` in a 32-bit calling convention will use a 4-byte stack slot (or take up a whole 4-byte register, whether or not it's sign-extended to the full register width).

---

Your last 2 questions are really asking the same thing:

You're compiling without optimization, so for consistent debugging every variable including function args needs a memory address where a debugger could modify the value when stopped at a breakpoint.  This includes `main`'s `argc` and `argv`, as well as the register args to `f1`.

If you defined `main` as `int main(void)` (which is one of two valid signatures for `main` in hosted C implementations, the other being `int main(int argc, char**argv)`), there'd be no incoming args for main to spill.

---

**If you compiled with optimization enabled, there'd be none of that crap**.  See [How to remove "noise" from GCC/clang assembly output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38552116/how-to-remove-noise-from-gcc-clang-assembly-output) for suggestions on how to get compilers to make asm that's nice to look at.  e.g. from [the Godbolt compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,source:'__attribute__((noinline,+noclone))%0D%0Aint+f1(int+a1,+int+a2,+int+a3,+int+a4,+int+a5,+int+a6,+int+a7,+int+a8,+int+a9)%0D%0A%7B%0D%0A++int+c+%3D+3%3B%0D%0A++int+d+%3D+4%3B%0D%0A++return+a1+%2B+a2+%2B+a3+%2B+a4+%2B+a5+%2B+a6+%2B+a7+%2B+a8+%2B+a9+%2B+c+%2B+d%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aint+main(int+argc,+char**+argv)%0D%0A%7B%0D%0A++f1(1,+2,+3,+4,+5,+6,+7,+8,+9)%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'C%2B%2B+source+%231',t:'0')),k:38.42077371489136,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:clang700,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'1',intel:'1',trim:'1'),lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:'-xc+-Wall++-O3+-fPIC+-shared',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+clang+7.0.0+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)+C%2B%2B',t:'0')),k:50,l:'4',m:50,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g82,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'1',intel:'1',trim:'1'),lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:'-xc+-Wall+-O3+-fPIC+-fverbose-asm',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+gcc+8.2+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%232)+C%2B%2B',t:'0')),header:(),k:50,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),k:61.57922628510863,l:'2',m:100,n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),l:'2',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),version:4), compiled with `gcc -O3 -fPIC`<sup>1</sup>, you get:

```
f1:
    addl    %esi, %edi      # a2, tmp106    # tmp106 = a1 + a2
    movl    8(%rsp), %eax   # a7, tmp110
    addl    %edx, %edi      # a3, tmp107
    addl    %ecx, %edi      # a4, tmp108
    addl    %r8d, %edi      # a5, tmp109
    addl    %r9d, %edi      # a6, tmp110
    addl    %edi, %eax      # tmp110, tmp110
    addl    16(%rsp), %eax  # a8, tmp112
    addl    24(%rsp), %eax  # a9, tmp113
    addl    $7, %eax        #, tmp105       # c+d = constant 7
    ret
```

(I used AT&T syntax instead of Intel because you used that in your question)

IDK exactly why gcc reserves somewhat more stack space than it actually needs; this sometimes happens even with optimization enabled.  e.g. gcc's `main` looks like this:

```
# gcc -O3
main:
    subq    $16, %rsp    # useless; the space isn't used and it doesn't change stack alignment.
    movl    $6, %r9d
    movl    $5, %r8d
    movl    $4, %ecx
    pushq   $9
    movl    $3, %edx
    movl    $2, %esi
    movl    $1, %edi
    pushq   $8
    pushq   $7
    call    f1@PLT
    xorl    %eax, %eax    # implicit return 0
    addq    $40, %rsp
    ret
```

**All the extra crap that's going on in your version of the function is a consequence of the anti-optimizations required for consistent debugging, which you get with the default `-O0`.**  (Consistent debugging means you can `set` a variable when stopped at a breakpoint, and even `jump` to another source line inside the same function, and the program will still run and work as you'd expect in the C abstract machine.  So the compiler can't keep anything in registers across statements, or optimize based on anything other than literal constants inside a statement.)

`-O0` also means compile fast, and don't try to allocate stack space efficiently.

---

Footnote 1: `-fPIC` prevents gcc from optimizing away the call in `main`.

Without that, even with `__attribute__((noinline))`, it can see that the function has no side effects so it can just omit the call instead of inlining it and optimizing it away.

But `-fPIC` means generate code for a shared library, which (when targeting Linux) means symbol interposition is possible, so the compiler can't assume `call f1@plt` will actually call *this* definition of `f1`, and thus can't optimize based on it having no side effects.

clang apparently assumes that it still can optimize that way even with `-fPIC`, so I guess clang assumes that conflicting definitions of the same function are not allowed or something?  This would seem to break LD_PRELOAD overrides of library functions for calls from within the library.