# x86-64 size of parameters pushed on stack

Tags: assembly, memory-management, stack, x86-64, calling-convention

What is the size of excessive parameters passed via stack?

C code:

```
int f(int a, int b, int c, int d, int e, int f, int g, int h, int i) {f = 8; g = 3; h=9; i = 12; return g;}

int main() {
        f(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9);
        return 0;
}
```

is compiled with `gcc -S -masm=intel sth.c` to:

```
       .file   "passord.c"
        .intel_syntax noprefix
        .text
        .globl  f
        .type   f, @function
f:
.LFB0:
        .cfi_startproc
        push    rbp
        .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
        .cfi_offset 6, -16
        mov     rbp, rsp
        .cfi_def_cfa_register 6
        mov     DWORD PTR -4[rbp], edi
        mov     DWORD PTR -8[rbp], esi
        mov     DWORD PTR -12[rbp], edx
        mov     DWORD PTR -16[rbp], ecx
        mov     DWORD PTR -20[rbp], r8d
        mov     DWORD PTR -24[rbp], r9d
        mov     DWORD PTR -24[rbp], 8
        mov     DWORD PTR 16[rbp], 3 ; HERE
        mov     DWORD PTR 24[rbp], 9 ; HERE
        mov     DWORD PTR 32[rbp], 12
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR 16[rbp]
        pop     rbp
        .cfi_def_cfa 7, 8
        ret
        .cfi_endproc
.LFE0:
        .size   f, .-f
        .globl  main
        .type   main, @function
main:
.LFB1:
        .cfi_startproc
        push    rbp
        .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
        .cfi_offset 6, -16
        mov     rbp, rsp
        .cfi_def_cfa_register 6
        push    9
        push    8
        push    7
        mov     r9d, 6
        mov     r8d, 5
        mov     ecx, 4
        mov     edx, 3
        mov     esi, 2
        mov     edi, 1
        call    f
        add     rsp, 24
        mov     eax, 0
        leave
        .cfi_def_cfa 7, 8
        ret
        .cfi_endproc
.LFE1:
        .size   main, .-main
        .ident  "GCC: (Debian 12.2.0-14) 12.2.0"
        .section        .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
```

My fragment of interest is:

```
        mov     DWORD PTR 16[rbp], 3
        mov     DWORD PTR 24[rbp], 9
```

The difference between 7th and 8th argument is 8 bytes, whereas the parameters from registers are saved in local memory as 4-byte values. However, all arguments are integers. Why parameters are pushed on stack using 8-byte space?

What I have found up to this moment is page 17 from [V ABI](https://www.uclibc.org/docs/psABI-x86_64.pdf). However I am not sure, why does it happen.

Comment: Each parameter gets one or more stack slots.  Each stack slot is 8 bytes.  This is so the caller can use `push` instructions to push arguments onto the stack.

Comment: duplicate of [Why does gcc pass char type in 8 byte format to function assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31498121), but stay tuned for an edit re: the tradeoff if I end up updating it.  Probably the ability to use `push` was the major design consideration, since even stuff like `printf("... "%6$*7$%d", ...)` that wants to index the args like an array can't do that, because `(long double)3.3` takes two slots for example.

Comment: I finished / got tired of editing (for now) an update to my answer on the now-linked duplicate.  @fuz, I think another major reason is robustness with sloppy code, like implicit declarations of functions taking `char` or `short` args, or stuff like `printf("%d %d", sizeof(foo), 1)` which probably existed in real code-bases in 2000 when x86-64 Sys V was designed.

Comment: This is a closely related question, but I would never come up with an idea to google chars instead of ints, since I've been experimenting with ints.

Comment: Sure, nobody's saying you should have found the duplicate on your own.  I hadn't remember it was asking about `char`, I found it by searching on `site:stackoverflow.com why are stack args 8 bytes` - Part of being an SO veteran and/or a subject-matter-expert is knowing what kind of phrasing would be found in an answer, and also having a vague memory that a few such questions existed. Having written answers to at least two of them helps in my case; I can often tack my last name onto a google search to narrow things down to ones I've commented on or answered when I have one in mind :P

Comment: I did upvote this even though it's a duplicate, since you found the ABI doc and are wondering *why* the rule is designed that way.  That's a more interesting question than just what the rule is.  Hrm, given how much I ended up writing, maybe it should be 2 separate questions that link each other, to un-bury the simple ABI-quote part of my answer, which is somewhat less visible after my last edit.  (Which I'm sure could say the same thing in less space, I just haven't figured out what order to put all the interlocking pieces.)