# Where to place the stack and load the kernel

Tags: assembly, stack, x86-16, osdev, real-mode

I'm new to operating system development and I'm curious about a problem I've run into while developing my own bootloader. My operating system is going to be written in assembly and will run in 16-bit real mode.

I know what the stack is and I have the impression that it grows downwards into the memory. Correct me if I'm mistaken. I know how to load a basic kernel into the memory from a floppy disc and I don't believe that is the problem.

The problem I'm running into is that I'm unsure where to place the stack and load my kernel into memory. I've tried creating my stack like this and I'm running into problems:

```
mov ax, 0x0000
mov ss, ax
mov sp, 0xFFFF
```

I'm loading my kernel at `0x1000:0x0000`. When I *PUSH* and later *POP* the volatile registers in my `print` function, my kernel just hangs the **second** time I do `call print`. This is my `print` function:

```
print:
    push ax
    push bx
    push cx

    mov al, [si]
    cmp al, 0
    je p_Done

    cmp al, 9
    je p_Tab

    mov ah, 0xE
    int 0x10

    cmp al, 10
    je p_NewLine
   p_Return:
    inc si
    jmp print
  p_Tab:
    xor cx, cx
   p_Tab_Repeat:
    cmp cx, 8
    je p_Return
    mov ah, 0xE
    mov al, " "
    int 0x10
    inc cx
    jmp p_Tab_Repeat
  p_NewLine:
    xor bx, bx
    mov ah, 0x3
    int 0x10

    mov dl, 0x00
    mov ah, 0x2
    int 0x10
    jmp p_Return
  p_Done:
    pop cx
    pop bx
    pop ax
    ret
```

These are the lines I want to display:

```
db "Kernel successfully loaded!", 10, 0
db 9, "Lmao, just a tab test!", 10, 0
```

This is the output I get when my kernel runs (the `_` is the cursor):

```
Kernel successfully loaded!
_
```

It successfully prints the first line, but hangs while printing the second. If I remove the *PUSH* and *POP* statements it works just fine. Why does my kernel hang when I attempt save and restore registers in my `print` function? Where should I place my stack and where should I load my kernel?

Comment: You're misaligning the stack. You should set SP to 0. That will put the first word pushed on to the stack at 0000:FFFE. But that's not your problem, which probably lies in code you haven't shown. Your code should work with the SS:SP initialized to 0000:FFFF and your code at 1000:0000.

Comment: Are you sure you're only going to need *one* stack? As soon as you're looking into multitasking, you are going to need "some more" of them.

Comment: @Ross Ridge Oh. Words are pushed onto the stack? Not bytes? I feel like this is something I should have known, but thank you for making me aware of this.

Comment: @tofro I'm making a mono-tasking kernel at the moment.

Comment: In 16-bit mode, pushes and pops are word-sized (i.e., 16 bits). Basically, a push is designed to push the contents of a register, so pushes/pops have the same size as the registers. Background information is here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15855444/366904

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It doesn't help that this isn't a [Minimal Complete Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) but your question suggests possible things to look for. Usually if code works by removing *PUSH*es and *POP*s in function prologue and epilogue, it usually means the stack was becoming unbalanced during the execution of the body of the function. An unbalanced stack will cause the *RET* instruction to return to whatever semi-random location is on the top of the stack. This will likely lead to apparent hangs and/or reboots. The behaviour will be undefined.

I haven't followed the logic in your code, but this stands out:

```
print:
    push ax
    push bx
    push cx

    ... snip out code for brevity  

    jmp print
```

At some point it is possible for your `print` function to be restarted at a point before all the pushes. This will cause more *PUSH*es onto the stack without corresponding *POP*s at the end. I think you might have been trying to get behavior like this:

```
print:
    push ax
    push bx
    push cx

.prloop:
    ... snip out code for brevity  

    jmp .prloop
```

The `.prloop` label appears at the top of the function but after the pushes. This prevents excess values being placed on the stack. `.prloop` can be any valid label of your choice.

---

The stack can be placed anywhere in memory that isn't being used by the system and doesn't interfere with your bootloader and/or kernel code. As @RossRidge points out, using an *SP* of 0xFFFF misaligns the stack because it is an odd address (0xFFFF=-1). The x86 won't complain (absent the Alignment Check flag) but it can hurt stack performance on some x86 architectures.

Note: setting *SS*:*SP* to 0x1000:0x0000 will cause the stack to run from 0x1000:0xFFFF down to 0x1000:0x0000. The first 16-bit value pushed will be at 0x1000:0xFFFE.

---

Your kernel and stack are generally safe anywhere between physical address 0x00520 and 0x90000 as long as they don't conflict with one another. On some systems the upper part of the memory region between 0x90000 and 0xA0000 may not be available. If you want to use this memory area I would avoid the area between 0x9C000 and 0xA0000. This area can be used by the BIOS as part of the [Extended BIOS Data Area](http://wiki.osdev.org/Memory_Map_(x86)) (EBDA).

The exact amount of usable Low Memory Area (LMA) space can be learned by calling the ROM-BIOS's interrupt 12h service, or directly reading the word at 0x00413. In either case, the result is the amount of KiB of usable memory. If there is less than 640 KiB of actual memory, and/or some of the memory at the LMA's top is used by the EBDA or other software, then the result will be lower than 640 (that is, 0x0280). Technically the result can be higher than 640 too. By multiplying or left-shifting the amount in KiB, the equivalent amount in paragraphs or bytes can be calculated.

The region between 0x00000 and 0x00520 should not be used as it contains the real mode interrupt vector table, the [BIOS Data Area](http://www.bioscentral.com/misc/bda.htm) (BDA) and 32 bytes of memory that is considered to be reserved.

Comment: Yeah, I don't know why I didn't notice that really blatant bug. Well thank you for the answer, this helps a lot. :)

Comment: Hang on, so would my stack run from 0x1000:0xFFFF if it's set at 0x1000:0x0000? That seems a little odd.

Comment: @DrCereal : Yes. This is a peculiarity with the segment offset architecture in 16-bit code. When you do a _PUSH_ in 16-bit the offset (*SP*) is decremented by two before the data is put on the stack. The segment is not altered in anyway. If you take 0x0000 and subtract two you get 0xFFFE. Since the segment is not altered you end up with 0x1000:0xFFFE. If you want to have a stack that runs from physical address 0x00000 to 0x0FFFF you could set SS:SP to 0x0000:0x0000 . In that case 1st push would decrement SP by 2 and place value there. That would be memory address 0x0000:0xfffe .